# save data under a ordered core data relationship

Tags: swift, core-data, tableview, relationship

In my swift code below the goal is to save a string to a core data relationship. In class two there is a func that adds a string to the tableview in that class. But that added string is only displayed under the name that is selected in parent class View controller. I have added a gif below to show what I am looking for.

[Gif of what I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDDFq.gif)

Core data table

[core data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NjD7.png)

```
  import UIKit;import CoreData


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?
    var items : [Person]?
    
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var theTable: UITableView!
  
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guard let table = theTable else {
            print("theTable is nil")
            return
        }
        table.dataSource = self
        table.delegate = self

        
        
        fetchPeople()
        
    }
    
    
    
    func fetchPeople(){
        
        do {
            self.items = try context.fetch(Person.fetchRequest())
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.theTable.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch {
            
        }
    }
    @IBAction func ADDSTUFF(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "add person", message: "what is the time", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        alert.addTextField()
        
        
        let submitB = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default){(action) in
            
            let textfield = alert.textFields![0]
            
            let newPerson = Person(context: self.context)
            newPerson.name = textfield.text
            newPerson.age = 20
            
            
            do {
                try self.context.save()
            }
            catch {
                
            }
            
            
            self.fetchPeople()
            
        }
        
        
        
        
        
        alert.addAction(submitB)
        
        self.present(alert,animated: true, completion: nil)
        

        
    }
    
    
    func relationshipDemo(){
        
        var family = FamilyMembers(context : context)
        
        
        family.name = "ABC Family"
        
        
        var person = Person(context: context)
        
        
        person.name = "Maggie"
        
        person.family = family
        
        
        family.addToPeople(person)
        
        
        try! context.save()
        
        
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PersonCell", for: indexPath)
        
        
        let person = self.items![indexPath.row]
        
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = person.name
        return cell
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let person = self.items?[indexPath.row].name {
            let vcx = Two()
            vcx.valueMove = person // Assign the name to valueMove property
            vcx.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext // or .fullScreen
            self.present(vcx, animated: true)
        }
    }

 
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let action = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") {(action, view, completionHandler) in
            
            let personToRemove = self.items![indexPath.row]
            
            
            self.context.delete(personToRemove)
            
            do {
                try self.context.save()
            }
            
            catch {
    
            }
            
            self.fetchPeople()
            
        }
        
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
    }
 
}





class Two: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var nameLabel = UILabel()
    var twoTableA = UITableView()
    var addB = UIButton()
    var data = [String]() // Data source for the table view
    var backButton = UIButton()
    var valueMove = String()
    
    
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        [twoTableA, addB,nameLabel,backButton].forEach {
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            $0.layer.borderWidth = 1
        }
        
        addB.backgroundColor = .purple
     
        
        
        nameLabel.text = valueMove
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            nameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.10, constant: 0),
            nameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            
            
            twoTableA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.bottomAnchor),
            twoTableA.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.40, constant: 0),
            twoTableA.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            twoTableA.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            
            addB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: twoTableA.bottomAnchor),
            addB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.10, constant: 0),
            addB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            addB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            
            
            backButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addB.bottomAnchor),
            backButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.10, constant: 0),
            backButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            backButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        ])
        
        backButton.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
        backButton.setTitle("back", for: .normal)
        addB.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
        addB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addJohnson), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(back), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        twoTableA.dataSource = self
        twoTableA.delegate = self
        twoTableA.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }
    
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?
    @objc func back(){

        let controller = ViewController() // Assuming HomeVC is the view controller class you want to present
        controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
        controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen // or .overFullScreen or any other style you prefer
        self.dismiss( animated: true, completion: nil)

 
    }
    
    func relationshipDemo(){
        
        var family = FamilyMembers(context : context)
        
        
        family.name = "ABC Family"
        
        
        var person = Person(context: context)
        
        
        person.name = "Maggie"
        
        person.family = family
        
        
        family.addToPeople(person)
        
        
        try! context.save()
        
        
        
        
        
    }
    
    @objc func addJohnson() {
        data.append("Family Member")
        twoTableA.reloadData()
    }
    
    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: That GIF is pretty hard to understand. Can you describe what you want, and how it's different from what you have now?

Comment: If you see under Katy Perry family member is saved twice but under Maggie it is only saved once. I want to create a core data relationship that only saves family member to the corresponding name selected. I have updated the gif.

Comment: @TomHarrington i answered your question above thanks

Comment: OK but... you're asking about Core Data, only your sample code doesn't use Core Data at all. I mean, you create a managed object context but you never use it. You're not creating or using any managed objects anywhere in this code. What is it that you need here? Is this a Core Data issue or something unrelated?

Comment: @TomHarrington what I want to do is take preset string named family member and saved it under the selected name from class ViewController. Class two saves how many family members that certain person has. Thing of it like class Viewcontroller is the singer and class 2 lists there specific songs. To do this I would need to implement a core data relationship.

Comment: Does your app have any Core Data code at all aside from what’s shown in this question? Are you using managed objects anywhere? Your sample code seems to be using an array of strings.

Comment: @TomHarrington I add how I save names to core data in func ADDSTUFF in class ViewController which I added in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to point you in the right direction. A good answer is still impossible, though I've asked for more information several times, because your code snippet **still** does not show how you use Core Data.

Specifically: As of your most recent edit, your function called `ADDSTUFF` creates a managed object. None of your code ever uses managed objects. Your table view is using an array of strings that isn't read from or saved to Core Data. Maybe you used your managed objects somewhere else, maybe not. I have no idea how your GIF relates to your question.

So the first suggestion is, use some of those managed objects that you create, if you're not already doing so in some code you haven't posted.

Next, your `Person` entity has a relationship called `family`. This is a to-one relationship to an entity called `FamilyMembers`. Things that you probably need to do include:

- You should make this a to-many relationship, unless a `Person` can only have one family member.
- You should make use of this relationship. Either create a `FamilyMembers` or use one that already exists, and add that to the `family` relationship. If you don't know how to use relationships at all, read through Apple's [documentation on using relationships](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH17-SW1), which is quite good.

Finally, please take a look at StackOverflow's "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" page. People here are willing to help, but you need to try and work with them so that they can understand what help you need.

Comment: I added all of my code does that do anything?